# php Form to Email sanitizing

Tags: php, security, email, forms, sanitization

im using the following to send a contact us type form, iv looked into security and only found that you need to protect the From: bit of the mail function, as ive hardcoded this does that mean the script is spamproof / un-hijackable

```
$tenantname = $_POST['tenan']; 
$tenancyaddress = $_POST['tenancy'];
$alternativename = $_POST['alternativ'];
//and a few more
//then striptags on each variable

$to = "hardcoded@email.com";
$subject = "hardcoded subject here";
$message = "$tenantname etc rest of posted data";
$from = "noreply@email.com";
$headers = "From: $from";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: I believe you mean you need to protect the "To: bit of the mail function", since that's what you've actually hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

Unhijackable? Yes.

Spamproof? I wouldn't describe it as that, as the form can still be used to spam the target of the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using form data to create `$from` (not quite sure from your code), `$from` could be used to add additional headers (BCC/CC), kind of like SQL injection.

*Update*: Now with the code a bit more readable, I realize that shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Its called crlf(`\r\n`) injection and its nothing like sql injection.

Comment: I'd argue that it is similar, since like SQL injection you're able to end the current 'statement' (in this case a header), and add additional 'commands' (in this case headers).Since SQL injection is (should be?) well known to PHP developers (more so than crlf injection), it seemed like a good way to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few considerations  `$headers` must never be controlled by an attacker.  If they can control this variable then they can inject a crlf `\r\n` and turn this forum into an open spam gateway.   [PHP-Nuke](http://secunia.com/advisories/7776/) was vulnerable to this a while back.

The 2nd consideration is rate limiting.  A dumb bot is going to this this forum a few thousand times.  They might not even spamming,  but just scanning your site for sql injection to break in.   You should use reCapthca to prevent bots from submitting this forum.